# Invalid use of this in a non static member function

Tags: c++

I got the following class:

```
class Foo {
private:
    static float scale;

public:
    static float setScale(float scale);
};
```

When I am trying to implement setScale like this:

```
float Foo::setScale(float scale) {
   this->scale = scale;
   return scale;
}
```

It throws an error:

> Invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function.

I really don't get this since my function is marked static.

I saw some related questions but it didn't answer my question.

So how can I fix this?
I know I can change the names and don't use `this` but there probably is a solution for this?

EDIT: Also when I implement the function inside the class it still throws the same error.

Comment: Should `setScale()` be a static member function? Static member functions are member functions that aren't bound to a specific instance. A function that sets a data member on the current instance looks to be coupled with the actual object, so making it static is a contradiction to its intended behavior. Same goes for `scale`. Ask yourself if `scale` should be different or the same for every instance. If it should be the same, then make it static, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `static` member function is **not part of the class**. In other words, there is only one instance of it. Notice how you access them using the scope resolution operator(`Foo::setscale(1.f);`), instead of the member reference operator(`Foo.setscale(1.f)`), because they are **not members of instances of the class**.

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
  void DoSomething();
};
```

In this example, if I create a `Foo f` and call `f.DoSomething()`, what happens is that the compiler actually transforms `DoSomething()` into `DoSomething(Foo* this)` where `this` is the address of `f`.

However, since `static` member functions are **not part of the class**, the compiler does not transform them to take in a `this` pointer.

P.S. So why have `static` **member** functions? For one, you can limit the scope of the function to the class it is declared in.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3):

`this` pointer is not there in static member functions of class. Change the definition as follows:-

```
float Foo::setScale(float s) {
   Foo::scale = s;
   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the function definition the following way

```
float Foo::setScale(float scale) {
   Foo::scale = scale;
}
```

static member functions have no implicit parameter this.

In the note of paragraph #2 of section 9.4.1 Static member functions of the C++ Standard there is explicitly written that

> 2 [ Note: A static member function does not have a this pointer
>   (9.3.2). —end note ]

Also you have to define the function as having return type `void` because at least you are returning nothing from the function.

```
void Foo::setScale(float scale) {
   Foo::scale = scale;
}
```

Comment: @broncoAbierto Function setScale declared as static. See the original post.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I had only looked at the variable.